# setting the ckeditor caret at the end of a new link

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, rich-text-editor

I am currently working on the ckeditor for a project,
We are using the link dialog plugin.

As said in the title I wish to make new links, and set the caret at the end of it.
The default behaviour selects the text in the editor once you add a new link.

I've been working around with the link.js plugin

I think I located where it happen, but I am not able to set my caret after the end of my a tag in all case (It works sometimes=> it places the caret at the end, but after some tries it does put it at the begining of my link)

Here is a sample of what it does : 
first time : [a href="#"]my link[/a]^
after some tries : [a href="#"]my link[/a][a href="#"]my link[/a]^[a href="#"]my link[/a]

the code inside the onOk method of the link plugin:

```
//I've commented the line under to have no selection : it works
//range.select();
// According to the doc, this should do the job ??
range.moveToPosition(text, CKEDITOR.POSITION_AFTER_END);
```

Thank you for your attention.

Dre.

Answer (score 1):

I know the previous answer and question are old, but I had exactly the same issue & didn't immediately find a proper working solution. Using the answer of @oleq I got the `"getParent of null"` error.

Instead of touching the core or overwriting core functions (such as `onOk`), you can leverage event listeners. In this case the `onHide` from the [dialogDefinition](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dialog_definition.html#property-onHide) as it's only called once right before closing the dialog.

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {

        var dialogName = ev.data.name,
            dialogDefinition = evt.data.definition;

        // Only in case of the link dialog
        if ( dialogName === 'link' ) {
            dialogDefinition.on('hide', function (e) {
                var sel = ev.editor.getSelection(), // Current Selection
                    range = sel.getRanges()[0];
                range.moveToPosition(sel.getStartElement(), CKEDITOR. POSITION_AFTER_END);
                range.select();
            });
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that without touching the core of the plugin. The strategy is to execute the default dialog's `onOk` and then simply adjust the selection to your needs ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/5wkc64ag/)). To to do this, you need to overwrite default `onOk` on `dialogDefinition` event in the first place:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( evt ) {
    var dialogName = evt.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = evt.data.definition;
    var editor = evt.editor;

    if ( dialogName == 'link' ) {
        var defaultOnOk = dialogDefinition.onOk;

        dialogDefinition.onOk = function() {            
            defaultOnOk.apply( this, arguments );

            var sel = editor.getSelection(),
                range = sel.getRanges()[ 0 ],
                path = range.startPath();

            range.moveToPosition( path.contains( 'a' ), CKEDITOR.POSITION_AFTER_END );
            range.select();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Olek, thank ou for the answer,
after doin that I got the following error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getParent' of null
I've removed the select action cause I don't want my text to be selected, anyway, because of that error my dialog won't close..